# How can I start an interactive session at breakpoint in VS Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

[image: Typical Situation in VS Code]

Above is a typical situation that I encounter. We hit an exception and now would like to get some more details about what went wrong. This is where I wish I could just jump right into an interactive python session and try to run the marked line manually to find out e.g. what the find_many might look like and if it actually does have a select method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Debug Console](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) is what you are looking for. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and type `debug console` if you do not find the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift+enter` or manual select the option like the following picture with the right mouse button.

[image]